# Flutter Storefront API

Tags: flutter, api, shopify-api, storefront

I want to fetch data from my Shopify webshop using the storefront API.
I am using the flutter_graphql package.

In the the flutter graphql package the documentation shows a snippet:

```
void main() {
  HttpLink link = HttpLink(
    uri: 'https://api.github.com/graphql',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Authorization': 'Bearer <YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN>',
    },
  );
```

Using the uri does not work, "The named parameter 'uri' isn't defined".
I have found similiar questions but no answers, this seems (what I know of) being the only way of using the token what I have found.

Comment: Question 2 has now been resolved. I changed the "return Text(TestGraphQL)